# Write Output to a local file and fetch from Control Machine in Ansible for Windows

Tags: ansible

I've tested the following tasks for my playbook (*which worked in Linux host*) on Windows host but it seems to be unsuccessful

```
  - name: Create local report
    delegate_to: localhost
    file:
      dest: /tmp/report.csv
      state: touch

  - name: fetch file
    local_action:
      module: lineinfile
      dest: /tmp/report.csv
      line: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
      insertafter: EOF
```

I don't know if there are special modules for similar tasks on Windows host.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `delegate_to: localhost` and `local_action`. This means both actions are executed on the server running the playbook (you can look [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) for additional info about delegation). This should work:

```
    - name: Create local report
      file:
        dest: /tmp/report.csv
        state: touch

    - name: fetch file
      lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/report.csv
        line: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
        insertafter: EOF
```